# Avoid rehydration of entities on id update nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a situation where I don't want to rehydrate a referenced object and just want to update the id column on an object.

```
public AppointmentMap() {

Table("appointment");   
Id(x => x.appointment_id).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("appointment_id");
References(x => x.actiongroup).Column("appointment_actiongroup_id");
References(x => x.resource).Column("appointment_resource_id");
References(x => x.client).Column("appointment_client_id");

... Other fields
```

I want to be able to update the appointment_client_id upon saving but still have the client object for display purposes. I don't want to make exceptional situations using DTOs or other constructs if this situation does everything I need except the part where I want to save the appointment_client_id by setting its integer value. I am using sessionless transactions and because the application service I'm running will be wrapped with a web service I do not wish to use sessionful transactions.

Short question can you save an object with its id change only without having rehydration take place. There are hundreds of places in my application that I need this in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A technique we can usu, is to map both: `Reference` and the `ReferenceId`. One of them just must be marked as `insert="false"` `update="false"`

```
// readonly reference with all the stuff for querying
References(x => x.actiongroup)
  .Column("appointment_actiongroup_id")
  .Not.Insert().Not.Update();

// the only editable mapping
Map(x => x.actiongroupId, "appointment_actiongroup_id");
```

I use the inversed approach, the ReferenceId is readonly, becuase now it is hard to manage the correct ID during the INSERT... but this is working

Comment: So far this seems to be the only way. I was trying all types of things for hours and finally came up with the same solution. I would love to know if there is anything negative about doing this. I will test more of this solution tomorrow as my battery died as soon as I saw this working. So far you seem to have the only solution.

Comment: Well I am using the doubled (reference and referencedId) mapping for really a long time. It is working. What could be even better for you - to set reference to allow Insert(), but Not.Update(), - and set referenceId to Not.Insert() - but Update() ... simply, we can play with ;) Enjoy NHibernate

Comment: I know this may seem obvious to you but tell me if I am correct this would allow me to create a new referenced entity and have it inserted but I will lose updates onthose entities. But what I gain is being to change which entity I point to by allowing me to update the referenced.  I probably would not edit referenced objects anyway as I am using a repository approach anyway with nhibernate on a web service and am using the mapping to reduce workload of data retrieval.

Comment: I would say: yes. But just test it, create few unit tests on very few "adjusted" entities and references... The behaviour should not surprise you ;)